# Anti-aliasing in Gvim

Tags: xubuntu, gvim

Apparently there's no anti-aliasing in vim-gtk in Xubuntu so the console version looks better than GUI one. Is there a way to turn it on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `vim-gnome` instead of `vim-gtk` solved the problem.